# Blog count in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to get the count of blogs by an author in `views.py` - `author_blog_count` but it is giving incorrect value. What can be the correct way of doing it?

**models.py:**

```py
class Blog(models.Model):

    author  = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='blogger')
    created_date  = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date  = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py:**

```py
def get_queryset(self):
        return (Blog.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
                            .order_by('-published_date')
                            .annotate(
                                  author_blog_count=Count('author__blogger'),
                                  author_total_likes = Count('author__blogs__likes')
                                     )
                            .annotate(sum = (F('author_blog_count')+F('author_total_likes'))))
```

**HTML:**

```
  {% for blog in blog_list %}
      <div class="container" id ="main-cont">
         <div class="blog" id ="blog_cont">
            <a href="{% url 'blog_detail' pk=blog.pk %}" {{ blog.title }}</a> 
             {{ blog.description}}<br>{{blog.sum}}
              <br><br>
             <form method = "blog">
                   {% csrf_token %}
                   {{form}}
             </form>
             <a href="{% url 'blog_detail' pk=blog.pk %}"></a></div></div>
```

**Error:**

> Reverse for `blog_detail` with keyword arguments `{'pk': ''}` not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: `['blog/blog/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Blog.objects.filter(...you filter).values('author').annotate(blog_count=Count('id')).order_by('author')<br><br>
```

Equivalant SQL statement :

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as blog_count, author
FROM Blog
GROUP BY author order by author;
```

Comment: I have tried this and it shows error because I am already using the filter on 'published date' and want to display it according to date. I think the problem is with the two count functions I am using because if I comment 'author_total_likes' then it gives the correct total else incorrect. But I am trying to get the sum of both. updated my view

Comment: Can you add the traceback too?

Comment: Added the html and error (if I try your code.) I am not getting any error with mine but just the incorrect sum

Comment: Error traceback